# Move the last visible pseudo element 12px to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to move the last visible pseudo-element 12px to left. This rule moves all visible pseudo-elements 12px to left:

```
document.styleSheets[0].addRule('.dataTable thead tr th.sorting:before', 'right: 12px;');
```

I need something like jQuery's `find(':visible:last')`. Other approaches are also welcome.

[image]
http://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/2qpgjw0b/

Comment: Use `:last-child` in the selector. Although you should note it would be a *far* better idea to do this in CSS, if possible.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

Comment: @Alexander..... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right

Comment: @epascarello , of course. The property and positioning are used together.. You are right!

Comment: visible "last-child". It is not the last child. Please check the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to select all visible element and apply the logic when widow resize. As you can notice a visible element doesn't have `display:none` on its style, so you can use attribute selector on `style` with `:not()` like this:

```
$('.dataTable thead tr th.sorting:not([style*=none])').last()
```

You select all the element without `none` in the style and then use `.last()` to only get the last one. But with jQuery you cannot manipulate `:after` element so you can add a specific class to this element and use CSS to apply style to pseudo element. So your code will be something like this :

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  /*Remove the class from the previous element */
  $('.special').removeClass('special');

  /*Add the class to only the last visible element*/
  $('.dataTable thead tr th.sorting:not([style*=none])').last().addClass('special');
})
```

```css
.special:after {
  right: 15px;
}
```

Here is a working example where I change color of only the **last vsibile** element (resize window to see) :

http://jsfiddle.net/2qpgjw0b/5/

Comment: This does not work because it is not the visible one. The last child is not visible (display: none). Please check the jsfiddle example.

Comment: @ThomasMüller oh i see ! it's a dynamic table, ok will update my answer ;)